# Cross-referencing between two lists in Python?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

List #1:

```
a=[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John Mark",
        "alias": "Batman",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Luke Ben",
        "alias": "Spider",
    }
]
```

List #2:

```
b=[
    {
        "uid": 1,
        "item": "eggs",
        "completed": False
    },
    {
        "uid": 1,
        "item": "milk",
        "completed": False
    },
    {
        "uid": 2,
        "item": "bread",
        "completed": False
    },
    {
        "uid": 2,
        "item": "cheese",
        "completed": True
    }
]
```

Expected outcome:

```
result=[
    {
        'name': 'John Mark',
        'alias': 'Batman',
        'shoppinglist': [
            'eggs',
            'milk'
        ]
    },
    {
        'name': 'Luke Ben',
        'alias': 'Spider',
        'shoppinglist': [
            'bread',
            'cheese'
        ]
    }
]
```

I have two lists and I need to create a new list of dictionaries by cross-referencing the two.

I have started to try making a new list to store the id/uid in a separate list but that did not work.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so that we can help you find where the problem is.

Comment: Show your new code please

Comment: Does "completed" affect the output? You cn just remove it if it doesn't.

Comment: userlist=[] 
        
        for user in a:
            userlist.append(user['id'])
        
        In [1]: print (userlist)
        [1, 2]

Comment: li = {} #store the shopping items
            for slist in b: 
                 for i in userlist:
                     li[i]=[]
                     if b['uid']==i:
                         print (i)
                         print (b['item'])
                         li[i].append(b['item'])
    
        1
        eggs
        1
        milk
        2
        bread
        2
        cheese

Comment: However, when I print the dictionary, the lists are empty.
    
        In [52]: print (li)
        {1: [], 2: []}

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to accumulate the shopping list like:

#### Code

```
users = {x['id']: x for x in a}
for x in b:
    user = users[x['uid']]
    user.setdefault('shoppinglist', []).append(x['item'])
result = [users[i['id']] for i in a]
```

#### Test Code:

```
a = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John Mark",
        "alias": "Batman",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Luke Ben",
        "alias": "Spider",
    }
]

b = [
    {
        "uid": 1,
        "item": "eggs",
        "completed": False
    },
    {
        "uid": 1,
        "item": "milk",
        "completed": False
    },
    {
        "uid": 2,
        "item": "bread",
        "completed": False
    },
    {
        "uid": 2,
        "item": "cheese",
        "completed": True
    }
]

users = {x['id']: x for x in a}
for x in b:
    user = users[x['uid']]
    user.setdefault('shoppinglist', []).append(x['item'])
result = [users[i['id']] for i in a]

print(result)
```

#### Results:

```
[
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'John Mark', 'alias': 'Batman', 'shoppinglist': ['eggs', 'milk']}, 
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Luke Ben', 'alias': 'Spider', 'shoppinglist': ['bread', 'cheese']}
]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Is `setdefault` the correct tool to use if I want to exclude 'id': 1 and 'alias': 'Batman'? I also only want to include items that have the key-value: "completed": False

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in userlist:
    ...:         li[i]=[]
    ...:         if b['uid']==i:
    ...:             print (i)
    ...:             print (b['item'])
    ...:             li[i].append(b['item'])
```

Every shopping item reinitializes the list. li[i] should only be initialized once by iterating through the user list first.

```
userlist = []
li = []

for user in b:
    userlist.append(user.id)
    li[user.id] = []
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in a:
    for y in b:
        if y['uid']== x['id']:
            x.setdefault('shoppinglist', []).append(y['item'])
print(a)
```

---

If you want customized items in `a`.

```
print([{y: x[y] for y in list(x) if y!='id' and y!='alias'} for x in a])
```

Output

```
[{'name': 'John Mark', 'shoppinglist': ['eggs', 'milk']}, {'name': 'Luke Ben', 'shoppinglist': ['bread', 'cheese']}]
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I still use `setdefault` if I want to exclude the other elements like `alias`?